# Accessing Coordinates in Nested JSON File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I'm trying to access lat/lng of polygons within a nested JSON file and trying to draw them using `new google.maps.Polygon()`, but having some troubles.

**UPDATE-2**: I am able to draw polygons, but it only draws the first polygon, not all 3: http://jsfiddle.net/vprbqaLm/10/

**UPDATE**: Check out my latest JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vprbqaLm/9/
Now I can't seem to read the coordinates as I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined`

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var coords = data.features.geometry.coordinates;
var paths = [];
for (i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < coords[i].length; j++) {
        var path = [];
        for (k = 0; k < coords[i][j].length; k++) {
            var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][j][k][1], coords[i][j][k][0]);
            path.push(ll);
        }
        paths.push(path);
    }
}
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: paths,
    strokeColor: "#FF7800",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    fillColor: "#46461F",
    fillOpacity: 1
});
return polygon;
```

Here is the sample JSON file:

```
    var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
            "id": 1,
            "properties": {
            "Name": "",
                "description": "",
                "timestamp": "",
                "begin": "",
                "end": "",
                "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
                "tessellate": 1,
                "extrude": -1,
                "visibility": -1
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-83.126571,
                    42.348706],
                    [-83.126520,
                    42.348634],
                    [-83.126516,
                    42.348635],
                    [-83.126147,
                    42.348778],
                    [-83.126144,
                    42.348780],
                    [-83.126195,
                    42.348852],
                    [-83.126199,
                    42.348851],
                    [-83.126568,
                    42.348708],
                    [-83.126571,
                    42.348706]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2,
            "properties": {
            "Name": "",
                "description": "",
                "timestamp": "",
                "begin": "",
                "end": "",
                "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
                "tessellate": 1,
                "extrude": -1,
                "visibility": -1
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-83.132805,
                    42.356496],
                    [-83.132753,
                    42.356423],
                    [-83.132751,
                    42.356424],
                    [-83.132243,
                    42.356624],
                    [-83.132241,
                    42.356625],
                    [-83.132294,
                    42.356698],
                    [-83.132296,
                    42.356697],
                    [-83.132802,
                    42.356497],
                    [-83.132805,
                    42.356496]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
            "id": 3,
            "properties": {
            "Name": "",
                "description": "",
                "timestamp": "",
                "begin": "",
                "end": "",
                "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
                "tessellate": 1,
                "extrude": -1,
                "visibility": -1
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-83.126776,
                    42.351813],
                    [-83.126492,
                    42.351413],
                    [-83.126189,
                    42.351525],
                    [-83.126191,
                    42.351528],
                    [-83.126376,
                    42.351807],
                    [-83.126776,
                    42.351813]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
};
```

Comment: I see some syntax errors. You should make a fiddle (I made one here: http://jsfiddle.net/jetweedy/vprbqaLm/) and mess around in it so we can share.

Comment: try to `console.log(ai.latLngs)` and see what you get.

Comment: @JonathanTweedy I added the Google Maps API so you can see the results on the console now: http://jsfiddle.net/vprbqaLm/1/

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in your question itself.

Comment: @JonathanTweedy What syntax errors? Can you point them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestion

first:: you can assign the coordinates without the

```
  $.each(polygons, function (i, n) {
   .....
  }
```

you already have the cooordinate in javascrip format `[[......],[.....]]` then you don't need to reassign to `paths[]`

second seem you have a nested [] of to much try with your format and then  with a minus nested level.

JSON coordinates literal example :

```
[[{"lat": 41.650299987709538, "lng": 12.536399034779624}, {"lat": 41.650331001957937, "lng": 12.53657301029202}, {"lat": 41.650344029686487, "lng": 12.537146999950506}, {"lat": 41.650474995651187 , "lng": 12.537842047638419}, {"lat": 41.650461970948285, "lng": 12.538146026115472}, {"lat": 41.65040398326272, "lng": 12.538020010393916}, {"lat": 41.650271995260688, "lng": 12.537231036701897}, {"lat": 41.650243023870289, "lng": 12.536492993378628}, {"lat": 41.650299987709538, "lng": 12.536399034779624}]]
```

If you can format as in the sample you can do the direct allocation otherwise you are obliged to convert each pair of numbers in the coordinates, add them to an array and then assign it to paths.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you see the JSFiddle here? http://jsfiddle.net/vprbqaLm/1/ I think they need to be passed as `new google.maps.LatLng()`.

Comment: I mean this :  `paths = polygons; ` . for each feature the coordinates in JSON are the path

Comment: Ok. I tried adding `data.features[i].geometry.coordinates` in paths but I get an error? `InvalidValueError: at index 0: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Comment: I have to apologize I had not noticed the fact that you are using only the numbers of the coordinates and do not use the object literal coordinates. I edited the answer that gives the example of a track that contains JSON coordinates directly usable like I mentioned before

Comment: I made the JSON file from a shapefile using QGIS. How can I format it like you have, but for hundreds of polygons?

Comment: For my use I write a simple transformation utility every couple of coordinate are wrappe with `{"lant": ` and `"lng:"`. If you have the shape file i think a regex could be useful. very fast to. In my case i start from KML, parse the data and store the polygon coordinate in DB for future use.

Comment: I do this for 40.000 100.000 polygons for singole  map

Comment: Do you have an example of that? Or how can I convert each pair of number to a coordinate, then add to array and then assign to paths?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80607/discussion-between-mapr-and-scaisedge).

Comment: i'm in chat and waiting

Comment: look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/pc7tux02/1/  this work fine. In your sample you don't plot the polygon inside the for cicle then you plot only the last, and second the path variable and polygons variable was declare in wrong place